# Pandas: from multi-line to single line observations

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index':['10a','10a','10a','20b','20b','20b','30c','30c','30c']
                   ,'var_vals': ['aaa','aaa','abb','bbb','bba','bbb','ccc','ccc','cab']
                   ,'var2_vals':['aga','aga','add','bgb','bbd','bgb','cdd','cdd','cda']})
display(df)
```

Looks like this:

```
    index   var_vals    var2_vals
0   10a     aaa         aga
1   10a     aaa         aga
2   10a     abb         add
3   20b     bbb         bgb
4   20b     bba         bbd
5   20b     bbb         bgb
6   30c     ccc         cdd
7   30c     ccc         cdd
8   30c     cab         cda
```

How does one turn the output into a single line with only what's different in a new column as such:

```
    index   var_vals     var_vals_0     var2_vals    var2_vals_0
0   10a     aaa             abb          aga            add
1   20b     bbb             bba          bgb            bbd
2   30c     ccc             cab          cdd            cda
```

I have tried groupby, pivot/pivot_table, stack/unstack, and melt but I either end up with immense dimensionality or data is lost.

Comment: Ok, this question has now be changed completely. I did a quick refactoring of my code with pd.concat(). Might be some smarter solution out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another one:

```
newdf = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('index')['var_vals'].unique().tolist()).fillna('')
```

1. tolist() passes the data back to list-format which gives us the ability to recreate the dataframe passing it once again to pd.DataFrame()
2. fillna handles the fact you can have different amount of uniques.

---

**Updated code:**

```
dfs = (pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('index')[i].unique().tolist()).fillna('').add_prefix(i+'_')
        for i in df.drop('index', 1))
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

**Full example**

import pandas as pd

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index':['10a','10a','10a','20b','20b','20b','30c','30c','30c']
                   ,'var_vals': ['aaa','aaa','abb','bbb','bba','bbb','ccc','ccc','cab']
                   ,'var2_vals':['aga','aga','add','bgb','bbd','bgb','cdd','cdd','cda']})

df = pd.concat(
    (pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('index')[i].unique().tolist()).fillna('').add_prefix(i+'_')
    for i in df.drop('index', 1)), axis=1)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
  var2_vals_0 var2_vals_1 var_vals_0 var_vals_1
0         aga         add        aaa        abb
1         bgb         bbd        bbb        bba
2         cdd         cda        ccc        cab
```

Answer (score 3):

One method via `groupby.apply`:

```
df.groupby('index')['var_vals'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.unique())).unstack()

         0    1
index          
10a    aaa  abb
20b    bbb  bba
30c    ccc  cab
```

Comment: Maybe not using `apply` :-)

Comment: Yeah, in that sense, @AntonvBR's method is better!

Comment: Ok yes, but actually they are all very similar.

Comment: Ah yes, I found a solution that does the same thing but the problem is I'm dealing with thousands of variables and I lose track of where the variable came from. In other words, the new variable name needs to show me where it came from e.g. "var_vals_0", "var_vals_1" etc

Comment: @Cibic that was not included in the first question. what do you mean came from? the index number?

Comment: So is there a specific way in which you want to decide what counts as `var_vals_0` as opposed to `var_vals_1`? Like maybe the order in which they appear?

Comment: I'd like to collect all the unique values for a particular observation and store them in a new variable if we have not already observed it. I don't mind some dimensionality increase. The order which they appear doesn't matter as much as retaining the data. Changing the original question to reflect this.

Comment: @Cibic yes sure, but isnt that what all these solution do?

Comment: @AntonvBR, yes all of them are correct. I was after recording the variable name a unique value came from so I can select them quickly later if that makes sense. Updated the original question

Answer (score 3):

Using `drop_duplicates` with `pivot`

```
df.drop_duplicates().assign(key=lambda x : x.groupby('index').cumcount()).pivot('index','key','var_vals')
Out[910]: 
key      0    1
index          
10a    aaa  abb
20b    bbb  bba
30c    ccc  cab
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @Wen !

Answer (score 3):

One more way using default constructor

```
x = df.drop_duplicates().groupby('index').var_vals.agg(list).to_dict()
pd.DataFrame(x).T

    0   1
10a aaa abb
20b bbb bba
30c ccc cab
```

Timings (marginally very similar I guess):

```
df = pd.concat([df]*10000).reset_index(drop=True)

%%timeit
x = df.drop_duplicates().groupby('index').var_vals.agg(list).to_dict()
pd.DataFrame(x).T
7.92 ms ± 224 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit 
df.drop_duplicates().assign(key=lambda x : x.groupby('index').cumcount()).pivot('index','key','var_vals')
8.81 ms ± 74.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
df.groupby('index')['var_vals'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.unique())).unstack()
8.83 ms ± 187 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('index')['var_vals'].unique().tolist())
13.3 ms ± 705 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yours solution is efficient even on higher data volume. In fact, when I isolate the each variable of interest and run your code to give a new dataframe I can add the variable's name as a prefix and then merge all of these together in the end.